# Is there an easy way to insert a current timestamp with the correct timezone in azure sql?

Tags: java, sql, azure, jpa

I'm using a Java JPA @query(...) tag where I use current_timestamp to insert a GTM time to the azure db table. I'm wondering if there is an easy way to set the timezone of the current_timestamp when I insert my timestamp. Something like

"UPDATE schema.tablename SET column = current_timestamp in zone 'timezone here'

Comment: What *exactly* is the type of the column? Show your DDL.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `timezone` in your query with any of the following ways to set time zone in java code.

1. Add `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`
2. Add `` @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")` on `createdOn() `` method

References: [spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone applied on writes but not on reads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60493632/spring-jpa-properties-hibernate-jdbc-time-zone-applied-on-writes-but-not-on-read) and [Timezone issue in Spring Boot JPA application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166851/timezone-issue-in-spring-boot-jpa-application)