# MySQL Date column returns from REST call with incorrect time

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, mariadb, react-admin

I have a MySQL table containing a DATETIME column, my_date.

This column is defined in my domain object as type `java.util.Date` and annotated as `Temporal`:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name="Thing")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Thing {
    ... 
    @Column(name="my_date", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date myDate;
    ...
}
```

The current `my_date` column value in the db is `2022-07-17 12:34:56`, per MySQL Workbench.

I have a pretty straightforward REST endpoint, created using Spring JPA, that for some reason pulls that value as:

```
...
"myDate": "2022-07-17T19:34:56.000+00:00"
...
```

Why would the time portion return with a value **7 hours later** than is showing in the database?

Update: I'm actually using MariaDB (10.7.3-MariaDB). Not sure if that's relevant here, but it just dawned on me, so mentioning it just in case that somehow could be the cause of the time portion getting offset.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60493632/spring-jpa-properties-hibernate-jdbc-time-zone-applied-on-writes-but-not-on-read may be helpful?  do you know what timezone you intend the stored times to be, and is that in fact what is being stored?  I don't *think* workbench does any timezone conversions before showing a datetime column value, but it does do a lot of crazy stuff; best to verify using the mysql command line client.

Comment: also, are you certain it is a datetime column, not a timestamp column?  datetime columns have no timezone information, and are stored exactly as clients specify, while timestamp columns always store a utc time, and convert to and from the client session's timezone every time they are written to or read from.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at that question. The mysql command line does return the same value as the workbench: 2022-07-17 12:34:56

Comment: The db column is defined as datetime. But maybe I need to change it to timestamp instead.

Comment: I much prefer datetime, where you aren't at the mercy of whatever client libraries set the timezone as.  and I think having the database possibly converting to the session timezone and then the client library also apparently doing some timezone conversion is going to be even worse.

Comment: Ugh, as it turns out, the issue seems to be a bug in React-Admin, as described here: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/5578. At this point, I actually think it has nothing to do with the Spring or the DB or anything else except this obscure bug in React-Admin.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the timezone problem, you can add code like below to Dockerfile for container of Mysql or you app

```
RUN rm /etc/localtime && ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime
```

##### update 1

according to https://javabydeveloper.com/temporal/

> The mapping between the Java 8 Date/Time classes and the SQL types is implicit, there is not need to specify the @Temporal annotation.

try remove @Temporal annotation

##### update 2

Is java.sql.Timestamp timezone specific?

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/14070771/16702058

> For example: Your local time zone is GMT+2. You store "2012-12-25 10:00:00 UTC". The actual value stored in the database is "2012-12-25 12:00:00". You retrieve it again: you get it back again as "2012-12-25 10:00:00 UTC" (but only if you retrieve it using getTimestamp(..)), but when another application accesses the database in time zone GMT+0, it will retrieve the timestamp as "2012-12-25 12:00:00 UTC".

Comment: I'm not using Docker.

Comment: ok, can you try changing @Temperal(timestamp) to @Temperal(datetime), I think if you use timestamp, it will treat the actual data as timestamp, and probably change the behavior when write and read to mysql server

Comment: I don't see a TemporalType of type datetime: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html.

Comment: which java version are you using?

Comment: if higher than java8, can you try remove the Temperal anno?

Comment: I guess although you specified the type of column in DB is datetime, but still it works as timestamp, cuz java.sql.Timestamp is the only option for transferring java.util.Date to java.sql.Timestamp?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67390608/16702058